# How do I send a command line input to another program that I cannot change with Python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have two programs - one that I am writing myself and one that I have to control a device that I cannot change. The program that controls the device is an .exe program that opens a command line input and I can manually type in commands like "stop", "init", etc. I want to be able to open this program with python and have python send it commands, but nothing I do seems to work. I can open the program both in the terminal and in another window, but I can't send it commands with the same python program. I have tried using both os.startfile and os.system to open the program, but when I open it in the terminal with os.system, the python program stops until I close the program and won't send any other commands. I have also tried subprocess, but again, I can't seem to get any of the commands to send to the other program (I tried both stdin.write() and communicate()). Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Tried:
`os.system(filename.exe)`

- Opens the file in the terminal, but I can't send commands to it

`os.startfile(filename.exe)`

- Opens the file in another window, but I don't know how to send commands to it

`proc = subprocess.Popen(filename.exe, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, text=True) proc.communicate("init") proc.communicate("stop")`

- Subprocess opens, but I can't send commands to it

Comment: Use the `pexpect` library to control an interactive application.

Comment: @Barmar if one needs to wait for specific outputs and "respond" to them, yes.